# CX20757 audio volume low Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my dual boot Win 10 & Ubuntu, when I tried to watch movie using SMPlayer, the volume is so low that I had to turn up the volume at 100%, but still it's very low. I found several fixes for ALC but not CX, I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu, can someone tell me step by step how to fix it? I run the `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` and it gave this output:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at e0610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

and `sudo aplay -l` and it gave this output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20757 Analog [CX20757 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks for your comment/suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution for this problem, after searching on the net, it's mentioned that PulseAudio Volume Control can boost the audio volume (it's different from Volume Control built-in apps in Ubuntu), install it and you can boost your audio volume above 100%. But what I'd like to know is there a solution for SMPlayer, it seems only audio in SMPlayer is low, other audio seems fine.

Thanks